# How can I measure the voltage of a capacitor using multimeter?

Tags: electrolytic-capacitor

I'm new to electronic and trying to measure a capacitor (Aluminum Electrolytic one) using a multimeter. The cap is already charged. What I did is to touch the positive leg of the cap with the red probe of the multimeter and the negative leg (the stripe side) with the black probe. To my surprise, it shows a minus sign preceding the volt number meaning that the side with stripe is positive. I tried three different caps with the same result. Why is that? Please kindly using some easy to understand explanations.

Comment: You connected red probe to Com, and black probe to the positive input? To the multimeter that is.

Comment: @MiNiMe No, the black probe is connected to the Com. I didn't connect the probes to the meter the wrong way.

Comment: Unless the multimeter is at fault, there's only one explanation left - the caps are charged the wrong way.

Comment: @MiNiMe Oh, thanks! I didn't even think of that. I assumed that the caps don't allow a reverse charging at all.

Comment: @preachers You can maybe get 1 V reverse on an alli electrolytic

Comment: @preachers Maybe the cap isn't charged in reverse, but you are misreading which side is positive and negative? We don't know how the cap is charged and what does it look like. Post a photo to see if you are understanding the cap correctly.

Comment: @Justme I think it WAS reverse charged, because I did it. This is the first time I measure a cap using multimeter. I'm trying to recap a PC motherboard. The caps are bulging and I have to replace them myself. I know, to measure a cap I have to pull them off the board. So I took them off and discharged them then measure(charge) them with my multimeter. I must have measured them the wrong way, cause I didn't think the caps could be charged that way or it must show me some odd behaviour, but it didn't. I then tried to measured the voltage, only at that time I noticed the polarity issue. My fault.

Comment: @preachers A multimeter can't charge capacitors. It is unclear what you are really doing and how, but yes, to measure a capacitor, it is correct that it must be removed first.

Comment: @Justme My multimeter has the function of measuring caps with capacitance less than 100mF. I assume that the capacitance measuring process itself charges the caps. And in fact, it does take some time. I have just discharged them and measured them again the right way. Now they show positive voltage when I measure them in voltage mode.

Comment: @preachers Measuring a capacitor by the most common method doesn't significantly charge it.